# How to plot a linear function using Gadfly.jl in Julia?

Tags: plot, graph, julia, gadfly

I am wondering how to graph a linear function (say y = 3x + 2) using Julia package Gadfly. One way I come up with is to plot two points on that line, and add `Geom.line`.

```
using Gadfly

function f(x)
    3 * x + 2
end

domains = [1, 100]
values = [f(i) for i in domains]
p = plot(x = domains, y = values, Geom.line)
img = SVG("test.svg", 6inch, 4inch)
draw(img, p)
```

[image]

Are there any better way to plot lines? I have found the [Functions and Expressions](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/man/plotting.html#Functions-and-Expressions-1) section on the Gadfly document. I am not sure how to use it with linear functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may plot the function directly, passing it as an argument to the `plot` command (as you pointed at [documentation](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/man/plotting/#Functions-and-Expressions-1)), followed by the start and end points at `X` axis (domain):

```
julia> using Gadfly

julia> f(x) = 3x + 2
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> plot(f, 1.0, 100.0)
```

[image]

Even more complex expressions can be plotted the same way:

```
julia> f3(x) = (x >= 2.0) ? -2.0x+1.0 : 2.0x+1.0
f3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> plot(f3, -5, 10)
```

[image]

If you want to plot two (or more) functions at same graph, you may pass an array of functions as the first argument:

```
julia> plot([f, f3], -5, 10)
```

[image]

<sub>tested with: Julia Version 0.5.0</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Most plotting tools simply accept a list of `x` values and a list of `y` values. This creates a series of `(x,y)` points which can then be plotted as individual points, connected by straight lines, connected by a best fit model, whatever you ask for.

Linear functions are completely defined by just two points so using a pair of points along with the `Geom.line` option should be sufficient. More generally you will want to use `linspace` to generate the points for your domain. These will then be passed into your function to generate the range values:

```
julia> using Gadfly

julia> f(x) = 3x + 2
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> domain = linspace(-2,2,100);

julia> range1 = f(domain);

julia> p = plot(x=domain, y=range1, Geom.line)

julia> img = SVG("test.svg", 6inch, 4inch)

julia> draw(img, p)
```

[image: Linear Plot]

Like I said before, a line is defined by two points so all of the extra points I added are superfluous in this case. However more generally you will need more points to accurately capture the shape of your function:

```
julia> range2 = sin(domain);

julia> p2 = plot(x=domain, y=range2, Geom.line)

julia> img2 = SVG("test2.svg", 6inch, 4inch)

julia> draw(img2, p2)
```

[image: Non-Linear Plot]

Comment: It seems unnecessarily verbose to use a comprehension here: `[f(x) for x in domain];` Better to use `f.(domain)`.

Comment: Good call, fixed.